# Parsing git-status

Tags: git, parsing, data-structures

Here are the status codes and their meanings from the [git-status docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_output). The same meaning is attached to several status codes. Is there a way to store this data that doesn't require me to manually create the entire tree but still enables the quick searching of a tree via an API something like `statuses.getMeaning(x, y)`?

```
X          Y     Meaning
-------------------------------------------------
          [MD]   not updated
M        [ MD]   updated in index
A        [ MD]   added to index
D         [ M]   deleted from index
R        [ MD]   renamed in index
C        [ MD]   copied in index
[MARC]           index and work tree matches
[ MARC]     M    work tree changed since index
[ MARC]     D    deleted in work tree
-------------------------------------------------
D           D    unmerged, both deleted
A           U    unmerged, added by us
U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
U           A    unmerged, added by them
D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
A           A    unmerged, both added
U           U    unmerged, both modified
-------------------------------------------------
?           ?    untracked
!           !    ignored
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Incidentally, after answering, I'm not sure what your question really was after all. Remember that this is summarizing the results of two separate `git diff` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not actually ambiguous.

There are two ways to see/view this:

- Unmerged states exist if and only if there are nonzero stage numbers, so you can check for that (`git ls-files --stage`).  This also lets you see every index entry, which may be useful depending on your final goal.
- Alternatively, observe that in the `--porcelain` output from `git status`, all but two unmerged states have at least one `U`.  The two that do not are `AA` and `DD`, and these two states cannot occur in any of the merge-not-in-progress cases: if X is `A`, Y is necessarily space, `M`, or `D`.  If Y is `D`, X is necessarily space or one of `MARC` (never `D`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just mean how can I structure this table of status codes in a way that is easily searchable and (hopefully) doesn't require me to type out each possible code?

Comment: You could just expand out the `[ MARC]` type items and end up with a big table. There are nine possible codes for each column (space, M, A, R, C, D, U, ?, !); while some can never occur in combination (you always get two ? or two !) that would give you an 81-element matrix, which you either index with X (or `to_value(X)`) and then Y (or `to_value(Y)`), or with combine(X,Y) (where the combine() function is up to you: do whatever makes sense for your programming language).

Comment: If you split off the `!` and `?` cases in advance, you're left with 7 codes per column, so that your table or matrix has 49 entries. Some of those can still never occur but this seems like the point of diminishing returns. If your programming language has easy dictionary lookups, though, you can build the minimal matrix, and use `meanings[X][Y]` where `meanings[X]` only exists for valid X, and the `[Y]` entry within that map exists only for Y valid for the given X.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. There seems to be some overlap. For example, `CD` can be both `'deleted in work tree'` and `'copied in index'`.

Comment: Sure: that means "comparing HEAD to index, we find a copy" and "comparing index to work-tree, we find a delete". Remember, this is the summary of *two* `git diff --name-status` operations: one from HEAD to index, and one from index to work-tree. If/when you expand these out, make sure that you keep both parts in the description.

Comment: Thanks! You've been really helpful!